# Can't sync discord.py commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I cannot sync discord.py commands

My try was this:

```py
        @bot.tree.command(name="test", description="My first application Command")
    async def my_command(interaction: discord.Interaction) -> None:
        await interaction.response.send_message("Hello from my command!")

    @bot.command(name="sync")
    async def sync(ctx):
        try:
            fmt = await ctx.bot.tree.sync(guild=ctx.guild)
            await ctx.send(
                f"Synced {len(fmt)} command(s) to the current server"
            )
        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.send(f"Error while syncing commands: {e}")
        return
```

But this doesn't seem to work. When I try to `!sync`, the bot takes ages to sync the one command, and doesn't even sync it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined your `my_command` command as a global command, ie you have not specified which server it is from via the `guild` parameter in `tree.command()`.
Therefore, for the command to be synchronized correctly, you need to synchronize your global commands, ie do not specify a `guild` for `tree.sync()`:

```py
fmt = await ctx.bot.tree.sync(guild=None)
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know ctx doesn't have a bot attribute. Try to remove the await ctx. in your code and it should work faster

Comment: This is not a thoughtful or productive answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).